# Проверка значения динамического массива

Tags: c++, сокет

### Проверка значения. Как записать короче, чтобы не перебирать по одному ?

> фрагмент кода: Необходимо разорвать соединение если получен "exit"

```
#define BUF_SIZE 4096
char* buf=new char[BUF_SIZE];

while (true) {
    ZeroMemory(buf, BUF_SIZE);

    //wait for client to send data
    int bytesReceived = recv(ClientSocket, buf, BUF_SIZE, 0);
    if (bytesReceived == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        cout << "Error in recv(). Quitting" << endl;
        break;
    }
    if(buf[0]=='e'&&buf[1] == 'x'&&buf[2] == 'i'&&buf[3] == 't')  //<<<<< ОПТИМИЗИРОВАТЬ
        bytesReceived=0;
    if (bytesReceived == 0) {
        cout << "client disconnected" << endl;
        break;
    }

    //echo message back to client
    send(ClientSocket, buf, bytesReceived + 1, 0);
}

//close the socket and cleanup
closesocket(ClientSocket);
WSACleanup();
delete[]buf;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо

```
if(buf[0]=='e'&&buf[1] == 'x'&&buf[2] == 'i'&&buf[3] == 't')  //<<<<< ОПТИМИЗИРОВАТЬ
```

используйте

```
if (memcmp(buf, "exit", 4)==0)  //<<<<< ОПТИМИЗИРОВАНО
```

Функция `memcmp()` возвращает `0` когда первые 2 параметре имеют тот же самые знаки на первых позициях, количество которых задано в третьем параметре.